# In oracle apex, which dynamic action fires a javascript event after all elements have loaded?

Tags: oracle-apex

#### Context

In Oracle Apex (currently 22.3), a page contains a tab strip with multiple tabs each containing various interactive reports and fields.

#### Problem

A dynamic action on `Page Load`, firing custom javascript code that references a specific tab region fails because the elements are not loaded. Is there another event that fires once all page elements have been loaded?